# regex: how to replace "\["?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, error

I have this sample line in the buffer:

```
export PS1="\[${Cyan}\]$(((SHLVL>1)) && echo "${SHLVL}\[${IBlack}\].")\[${IGreen}\]\u\[${IBlack}\]@\[${Purple}\]\h\[${IYellow}\] \w \$ \[${Color_Off}\]"
```

and i want to delete all `\[` so while the cursor is on the line i write `:s/\\[//g` and get the error

```
E486: Pattern not found: \\[//g
```

What do i do wrong? Somehow vim thinks that `//g` is part of the pattern?

When i search with `/\\[` i get proper results.

Comment: I'm not too sure but I /think/ this is a bug. I also could be wrong so I'm not posting this as an answer. However, to circumvent this, you can search \[ using /\\[ and then use `:s///g` Here, vim will use the old search term in the blank pattern

Comment: I suspect that ```\[``` has some special meaning which i do not understand and can't find it on google.

Comment: You can use the very nomagic mode like so:  `:s/\V\\[//g` (See `:help \V`)

Comment: I tried it, and it works if you escape the `[` like so: `:s/\\\[//g`

Comment: Yea i noticed it myself at the same time, it was malformed regex without closing ```]```. Thank you.

Comment: @Akshay: I think it's a bug, too. Posted [here on vim_dev](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/IGubDymd4iw/rqe7LDCwQZsJ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the reason: `[` is special character so vim treats next characters as part of the set (`[...]`) although it doesn't have the closing bracket. The proper replace should be:

```
:s/\\\[//g
```

(One backslash more)

Answer (score 3):

The error gives it away: Vim interprets the whole `\\[//g` as the pattern. It doesn't recognize the `/` separator because the `[` starts an (unclosed) collection. You either need to escape (via another backslash: `:s/\\\[//g`, or use *very nomagic* mode via `\V`: `:s/\V\\[//g`.

Comment: Just a small comment, `\V` means very _no_ magic

Comment: @Akshay: Right, corrected!

Answer (score 0):

If this would be slash, you could use another delimiter, however backslash (`\`) is metacharacter  which escapes any separator, so there is no way to omit two backslashes for backslash it-self. The same with `[`.

However using different delimiter can still improve the readability:

```
:s,\\\[,,g
:s@\\\[@@g
:s#\\\[##g
:s|\\\[||g
```

I've tried to test with `<Bslash>`,  but it seems substitute doesn't accept it.